# Match row value with column name and extract value in R

Tags: r, match

I have a table where I need to choose  all the values in the Data column, match with the column names and take the value from that row. Ex. Data column: choose A1, find column name with same name (A1 )and take the value (1),   choose A3, find column name with same name (A3) and take the value (11) and then print it to a table.

Can somebody help me, I am new using R and I do not know where to start.

```
A1  A2  A3   Data
1   5   9   A1  
2   6   10  A2
3   7   11  A3
4   8   12  A4
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

```
df[cbind(1:4, match(df$Data, names(df)))]
[1] "1"  "6"  "11" NA
```

Comment: I have tried but my results are only NA values, for every row I got one NA.

Answer (score 2):

If you create your data.frame with the row.names as your Data column, then it can be as simple as:

```
mydf <- read.table(text = "A1 A2 A3 Data 
1 5 9 A1
2 6 10 A2 
3 7 11 A3 
4 8 12 A4", header = TRUE, row.names = "Data")

sapply(row.names(mydf), function(x) mydf[[x, x]])
## $A1
## [1] 1
## 
## $A2
## [1] 6
## 
## $A3
## [1] 11
## 
## $A4
## NULL
##
```

`mydf[x,x]` simply returns the element of my df, in the row with the name x and the column with name x. You may need to tweak this output to match your goal.

Comment: I got only NULL values, do you have any clue why? tnx!

Comment: what are your `row.names(mydf)` and `names(mydf)`?

Comment: In my "Data" column I have duplicate values, so I could not use your suggestion read.table(), instead I used: rownames(df) = make.names(df$Data, unique=TRUE). It worked but it created extension on the names in the column, e.g "A1."," A1..2".Can I use sapply in this case as you suggested, but matching partially only the first 9 characters, and ignoring the rest? TNX so much!

Comment: I managed to grep, and then to do a sapply, but still I get NULL values.(my columns are class=numeric).Do you know what approach could I take from now? Thank you!  `
mydata2 <- mydata[grep("^A1", rownames(mydata)), ]

 sapply(row.names(mydata2), function(x) mydata2[[x, x]])`