# Create new R dataframe column based on conditions in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a date column, a column of ints (labelled `value` in the example below), and 12 other numeric columns, each corresponding to a month and labelled `X1` (jan) through `X12` (dec).

It looks something like:

```
date_var    value    X1       X2      X3     ...   X12
2016-01-01   100    1212     4161    9080    ...   383
2016-02-01   150    1212     4161    9080    ...   383
2016-03-01   150    1212     4161    9080    ...   383
```

What I'd like to do is create a new column, lets call it Z, which corresponds to the number in the `value` column, divided by the appropriate monthly value.

For example, in the table above Z for the `2016-01-01` entry would equal 100/1212, whereas the `2016-02-01` entry would instead divide by X2 for Feb and `2016-03-01` would have `value` divided by X3:

```
date_var    value    X1       X2      X3     ...   X12    Z
2016-01-01   100    1212     4161    9080    ...   383    0.0825
2016-02-01   150    1212     4161    9080    ...   383    0.0360
2016-03-01   150    1212     4161    9080    ...   383    0.0165
```

I've tried various approaches along the lines of attempting to divide `value` by `df[paste("X", month(df$date_var), sep = '')]`, although this returned list a rather than working element-wise so obviously isn't the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another good way using the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages basically takes the R approach of converting your information to long data frame format (i.e. the same kind of information in the same column, here all your X1-X12) and then uses a filter condition to only consider the month values that match the month in your date variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

# test data frame (code from parksw3)
data <- data_frame(
  date_var = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01")),
  value = c(100, 150, 150),
  X1 = rep(1212, 3),
  X2 = rep(4161, 3),
  X3 = rep(9080, 3),
  X12 = rep(383, 3)
) 

# calculate the resulting Z column
result <- data %>% 
  # gather all the month (X1-X12) values into long format 
  # with month_var and month_value as key/value pair
  gather(month_var, month_value, starts_with("X")) %>% 
  # only consider the month_value for the month_var that matches the date's month
  filter(month_var == paste0("X", month(date_var))) %>% 
  # calculate the derived quantity
  mutate(Z = value/month_value)

print(result)

##     date_var value month_var month_value          Z
##       <date> <dbl>     <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1 2016-01-01   100        X1        1212 0.08250825
## 2 2016-02-01   150        X2        4161 0.03604903
## 3 2016-03-01   150        X3        9080 0.01651982
```

If you want, you can merge it back into your original data frame:

```
data_all <- left_join(data, select(result, date_var, Z), by = "date_var")

print(data_all)

##     date_var value    X1    X2    X3   X12          Z
##       <date> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
## 1 2016-01-01   100  1212  4161  9080   383 0.08250825
## 2 2016-02-01   150  1212  4161  9080   383 0.03604903
## 3 2016-03-01   150  1212  4161  9080   383 0.01651982
```

Comment: Since date_var is already given in a date format, you can replace `as.numeric(format(date_var, "%m"))` with `month(date_var)`. Otherwise, this is great.

Comment: Ah right, great point, didn't have lubridate installed --> code example updated

Comment: I don't think you need lubridate. It works on mine without lubridate.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297540/match-row-value-with-column-name-and-extract-value-in-r). I think there should be a simpler way but here's what I did based on that post and they both seem to work:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
    date_var = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-02-01", "2016-03-01")),
    value = c(100, 150, 150),
    X1 = rep(1212, 3),
    X2 = rep(4161, 3),
    X3 = rep(9080, 3),
    X12 = rep(383, 3)
)
```

Method 1:

```
m <- paste0("X", month(df$date_var))
sub <- cbind(1:nrow(df),
    match(m, names(df))
)
Z2 <- df$value/as.numeric(df[sub])
df2 <- cbind(df, Z2)
```

Method 2:

```
Z3 <- sapply(rownames(df), function(x){
    with(df[x,],{
        m <- month(date_var)
        value/get(paste0("X", m))
    })
})
df3 <- cbind(df, Z3)
```

Result:

```
##     date_var value   X1   X2   X3 X12         Z3
## 1 2016-01-01   100 1212 4161 9080 383 0.08250825
## 2 2016-02-01   150 1212 4161 9080 383 0.03604903
## 3 2016-03-01   150 1212 4161 9080 383 0.01651982
## 4 2017-02-01   150 1212 4161 9080 383 0.03604903
```

Answer (score 1):

As an exploration into the trials of R indexing - a pseudo-`tidyverse` answer.

First let's generate some dummy data.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data_frame(
    date_var = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = 12),
    value = ceiling(runif(12, 100, 200))
)

data %>%
    mutate(months = map(value, function(x){matrix(ceiling(runif(12, 50, 5000)), ncol = 12)}),
           months = map(months, as_data_frame)) %>%
    unnest(months) %>%
    as.data.frame() ->
    sample.data

head(sample.data)
#>     date_var value   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12
#> 1 2016-01-01   147 2004 2456 3983 4464 2473 2824 2038 1354 3433   51  574 1381
#> 2 2016-02-01   170 2862 3579  543 1458 2472  826 3865  528  187  951 4732 1849
#> 3 2016-03-01   107 2860 1359 4366 1824  173 3541  624   76 4113  771  808 3457
#> 4 2016-04-01   115 1707 4015 3951 2774 2726 1789 2189 1903 1706  124 3679 1876
#> 5 2016-05-01   120 1058 4169 2594 4334  221  494 2032 1425 2525 3358  791 3691
#> 6 2016-06-01   191 4169  570 3245 1682 3811 4350 2344 4338 2258  779 1835 2480
```

Now that we have some sample data, we can use dual indexing to extract the value of each column, based on the month. I'm assuming that the months are named `V1` -- `V12` (as they are in my dataset).

```
sample.data %>%
    mutate(Z = .[cbind(seq_along(nrow(.)), match(sprintf("V%s", month(date_var)), names(.)))], 
           Z = as.numeric(Z),
           Z = value / Z) ->
    result

head(result)
#>     date_var value   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9  V10  V11  V12          Z
#> 1 2016-01-01   147 2004 2456 3983 4464 2473 2824 2038 1354 3433   51  574 1381 0.07335329
#> 2 2016-02-01   170 2862 3579  543 1458 2472  826 3865  528  187  951 4732 1849 0.06921824
#> 3 2016-03-01   107 2860 1359 4366 1824  173 3541  624   76 4113  771  808 3457 0.02686417
#> 4 2016-04-01   115 1707 4015 3951 2774 2726 1789 2189 1903 1706  124 3679 1876 0.02576165
#> 5 2016-05-01   120 1058 4169 2594 4334  221  494 2032 1425 2525 3358  791 3691 0.04852406
#> 6 2016-06-01   191 4169  570 3245 1682 3811 4350 2344 4338 2258  779 1835 2480 0.06763456
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way but you can use a for loop (assuming this is the layout of the data):

```
data = "yourData"
x = as.numeric(format(data[,1],"%m"))
for (i in 1:length(data[,1])){
data[i,"Z"] = data[i,2]/data[i,x[i]+2]
}
```